# why the ArrayList in onDataChange method of addValueEventListener of firebase is not null, but outisde it is null?

Tags: java, android, firebase

In my project I read data from Firebase and added my data in `Arraylist<object>`.

I create my `Arraylist` in oncreate() and used it in `onDataChange()`.

In `onDataChange` method of `addValueEventListener` the ArrayList is not null, it's read correctly. But outside it is read 0 (null). Why is that?

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private ArrayList<myObject> myListOfObjact;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


// Write a message to the database
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference();


        myListOfObjacts= new ArrayList<myObject>();

         Log.e(TAG, " myListOfObjacts.size: " + myListOfObjacts.size());
         // size of myListOfObjacts here is 0 (null) 

// Read from the database
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postsnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    myObject data1 = postsnapshot.getValue(myObject.class);
                    myListOfObjacts.add(data1);
                }

            Log.e(TAG, " myListOfObjacts.size: " + myListOfObjacts.size());
            // size of myListOfObjacts here is reading correctly 

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError error) {
                // Failed to read value
                Log.w(TAG, "Failed to read value.", error.toException());
            }
        });    

           Log.e(TAG, " myListOfObjacts.size: " + myListOfObjacts.size());
           // size of myListOfObjacts here also is 0 (null) 

    }

}
```

Comment: Because when you do `Log.e(TAG, " myListOfObjacts.size: " + myListOfObjacts.size());` the event listener has not yet been invoked

Answer (score 1):

The Firebase Database client performs all network and disk operations off the main thread.

The Firebase Database client invokes all callbacks to your code on the main thread.

Therefore, onDataChange() is almost always triggered after other main (UI) thread based methods such as onCreate(), onStart()... because onDataChange() relies on your device's internet speed. Actually the null value that you see was null at the time it was first logged or invoked, but not null at the time you see the values populated on your layout.

Comment: thank you to answer me ... but how could i solve this problem ?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're directing people to AsyncTask here.  It's completely not necessary in order to deal with Firebase APIs.  None of them ever block the main thread, and no mechanism is needed to move its work off the main thread.  In fact, AsyncTask is sadly outdated and shouldn't be used any more.  There are much better options.

Comment: I understand.  Threading is not easy.  My main concern is that directing someone to a utility that's not necessary here, and is not recommended any more by the Android team, could cause more confusion than it solves.

Answer (score 0):

addValueEventListener() is asynchronous, meaning it returns to the caller immediately, while the Firebase SDK goes and makes the request to the server while your code continues to execute.  The callback you pass to it happens some time later, *after* the request is complete.  You don't know how long that's going to be, and you shouldn't make any assumptions about that.  Right now, your code is assuming that the results are available immediately after you add the listener, and that's not valid.

If you want the results of a listener, you should only do that from within the listener.  You can't expect the results to be available before then.

If you want to know more about why Firebase APIs are asynchronous, [read this blog](https://medium.com/google-developers/why-are-the-firebase-apis-asynchronous-e037a6654a93).

Comment: You should probably add, how to make async calls to persist data outside onDataChange to apps which use RecyclerView to populate data which is returned from onDataChange.